# Allow photos in advancd forum replies?

Tags: files

I'm currently using the insert module to allow forum users to easily upload a image and insert it into the forum topic body. I'm looking for a way to allow users replying to a topic to do the same thing. So, for example, user A could create a thread titled "Post your photos on mountains here" and users could reply to the thread and post their photos.

I'm sure this is possible through the text editor with IMCE or similar, but I find that route to confusing for simple forum users. That's why i like the insert mod, select your file and hit upload/insert. simple. So, any alternatives or something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to add fields to comments.

From Structure -> Content Type select manage fields for the content type that needs image attached

There is a tab called "Comment Fields".

Select that, add and image field to it and that should do it. You would see an upload button in the comment.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed! Just as I expected, something simple that I over looked.